# JavaFX8 and controlsfx popover placement

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

Popover gets placed based off an x,y plane of your screen.  What I was looking to do is move it down to the add index button.  I am currently getting the x,y of my application based on the screen. But I have children nodes within children nodes on my scene. All these children nodes are added at 0,0.  So when I call to get an offset within each pane my x and y remain at 0. I am looking for a way to get the total offset from the scene all the way down to the add index button.

I currently use a recursive method to go from the parent pane of the button to root of the scene.

```
public Node rootnode (Node parent)
{
    if(parent.getId()=="root")
        return parent;
         x =+ parent.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
         y=+ parent.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();
     rootnode(parent.getParent());
     return parent;
}
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: good question, I have done the same thing with ugly stuffto get the good position? I'm interested by a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [Node.localToScene(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene%28double,%20double%29) methods.